# Tensorflow sparse tensor row-wise mask

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tf sparse tensor, and a mask for rows of the tensor's dense form.

E.g.

```
tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]],
    values=tf.constant([3, 40, 9, 5, 6, 4], tf.int64),
    dense_shape=[2, 10]
)
```

I have a mask [ True, False] and I would like to keep the 1st row as in the dense form, without converting the sparse tensor:

```
tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]],
    values=tf.constant([3, 40, 9], tf.int64),
    dense_shape=[1, 10]
)
```

How can I use the mask to directly filter the sparse tensor?

Comment: Do you have an example of the sparse tensor and mask? And your desired result?

Comment: yes, I edited in the initial question.

Comment: yes also added now

Comment: can you explain how you come to your desired result?

Comment: sorry my bad, omitted one value.. now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using a `boolean_mask` and `tf.sparse.slice`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]],
    values=tf.constant([3, 40, 9, 5, 6, 4], tf.int64),
    dense_shape=[2, 10])

mask = tf.constant([True, False])
indices = x.indices
start = tf.boolean_mask(indices, tf.where(tf.greater(indices[:, 0], 0), mask[1], mask[0]), axis=0)
result = tf.sparse.slice(x, start = start[0,:], size = tf.cast(tf.shape(tf.boolean_mask(tf.zeros(x.dense_shape), mask, axis=0)), dtype=tf.int64))
print(result)
```

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([ 3 40  9], shape=(3,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([ 1 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

Or with `tf.sparse.retain`, you can use the boolean mask directly on your sparse tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]],
    values=tf.constant([3, 40, 9, 5, 6, 4], tf.int64),
    dense_shape=[2, 10])

mask = tf.constant([True, False])
mask = tf.where(tf.greater(x.indices[:, 0], 0), mask[1], mask[0])
result = tf.sparse.retain(x, mask)
print(result)
```

However, this approach does not change the `dense_shape`:

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([ 3 40  9], shape=(3,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([ 2 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

But you can use `tf.sparse.reduce_sum` on `result` to get the sparse tensor with the correct `dense_shape`:

```
tf.sparse.reduce_sum(result, axis=0, keepdims=True, output_is_sparse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder how to generalize the method of reducing the dense shape, so it can apply to the sparse tensor with string values, and the rows are multiple instead of only 2, with the mask of random Trues and Falses?

Comment: Hmm..kindly post a new question with more details please @Joe

Comment: yes it's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72105416/removing-empty-rows-in-tf-sparse-tensor. Hope it's clear