# Removing empty rows in tf sparse tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

This a follow up question to [Tensorflow sparse tensor row-wise mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080281/tensorflow-sparse-tensor-row-wise-mask). It seems tf doesn't provide a convenient way to remove empty rows in the sparse tensor. e.g. from

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [3 0]
 [4 0]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([b'a', b'b', b'c', b'd', b'e'], shape=(5,), dtype=string), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([5 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

to

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 0]
 [3 0]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([b'a', b'b', b'c', b'd', b'e'], shape=(5,), dtype=string), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([4 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

How to deal with the case as above without converting the sparse to dense?

Thx, J